# PHP $_GET/$argv equivalent in Shell Script?

Tags: php, bash, shell, variables

In `PHP`, we can pass a variable into script from the file name as `file.php?key=value` or `file.php -key=value`. Is there any equivalent option to do so in Shell Script?

I want to run the script in terminal; **something like** `./file.sh -key=value` to pass the variable into the shell script for further processing.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php

Comment: You cannot pass query variables like you do in URLs. However, you can pass them as extra command line parameters passed after the command.

Comment: @ceejayoz it is not matter of PHP at all. Since I come with background in PHP I used this example to find its equivalent in shell.

Comment: It's worth noting that while you can pass parameters through command line, you **cannot pass them as key-value pairs**. Unless you use a format like a URI query and parse it yourself.

Comment: @Christian you're write there is no such thing as we have for URI query, but duskwuff's answer can solve my problem!

Comment: @Ali duskwuff's answer does not let you pass a URL query with key-value pairs. While it's an answer which hints to a solution, it's not the best answer, and it's definitely not written correctly from a technical perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes:

```
file.sh value1 value2
```

`value1` and `value2` will be exposed to the script in the variables `$1` and `$2`; the whole string `value1 value2` will also show up in `$*`.

You can use the `shift` shell builtin to get one variable at a time.

Comment: Yes?? Can you please read his question again? You can't pass arguments as if they were a URL query, but rather with spaces as you demonstrated, so the answer is pretty much a **no**.

Comment: Well, it *is* a way of passing options, it's just not the same as in a URL.

Comment: Quoting his question: *something like ./file.sh?key=value to pass the variable into the shell script for further processing.*

Comment: If PHP and URLs are all you know, that might seem like the only reasonable possible way of passing options, I guess? @tereško: Well, someone's gotta do it.

Comment: This is exactly what I meant and needed!

Comment: @Ali It's different from your question on two counts, and providing a delusional answer (like duskwuff's) isn't helpful. A casual reader would think *"oh, so I can pass URLs to any commandline program"*.

Comment: @Christian in that line, I quoted that I am running the script in terminal; so it is not the webserver processing of the URLs (as we do in PHP).

Comment: @Ali so the "yes" fails because you cannot pass a uri query via command line. You can pass arguments, but not a query. You asked for a query, so the answer is **"no, but...."** Is that so much hard to grasp? Did you read ExplosionPills' answer (did you see a "yes" floating in his')?

Answer (score 2):

The `_GET` and shell arguments are very different from one another.  `_GET` is an expansion of HTTP request parameters.  Shell scripts could technically process get requests and accept query string parameters, but I highly doubt that's what you want.  Instead, you can pass arguments to the script just by separating them with spaces (and using quotes as needed).

You can do this with many executables in the shell.  Even PHP scripts can accept these arguments, which are stored in `argv`.

Comment: I don't know why this got down-voted, it provides a concise and sensible answer.